# How can you guarantee that a password vault application is secure?

Tags: ios, password-protection, trust

I have a large number of user names and passwords - a different one for every website, service, ... To keep track of the information I have an iOS app that claims to store the information with RSA-256 encryption; it has the option of synchronizing the "vault" between different devices, so I can used either iPad or iPhone to access the information.

In essence, I "trust" the software provider that their claim that their software is secure is true. This means not only (1) that it's well written (no accidental security flaws), but also (2) that there is no "back door" that allows them to intercept or redirect my files during the synch operation - if they did, they would "have everything".

I wonder if there is a "best" way to address this issue. I can think of a few:

- write your own. Guarantees (2), but not (1)
- have an open source project, and let "the community" help with (1). Of course a malicious person might use the open source to find and exploit (rather than fix) a weakness
- Third party certification of a provider's software. Now you have to trust the third party...

There may be a robust solution to this - but I don't know it. Many "related" questions appear to exist on SO, but I couldn't find one that really answered this.

Any takers?